# Visual Studio build not including certificate

Tags: visual-studio, timestamp, clickonce, digital-signature

I'm trying to prevent my built .exe from triggering the Windows 10 "SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting".

Under Properties>Signing, I've created a "Test certificate" for the ClickOnce manifests (name.pfx), I'm using [this Timestamp URL](http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode), and I've signed the assembly using the same name.pfx as before. Under Properties>Security, I enabled ClickOnce security settings (full trust). However, when I build the .exe (the file that I distribute), I do not see any certificate under the Properties>Digital Signatures (in fact, the tab doesn't even show up).

What am I doing wrong?

With hope,
Conrad